2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #4 on Philosophy has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Congratulations, great job @causative!

Congratulations Causative.  We appreciate what you and our existing mods do to keep this place running!  Thanks you all!  Thanks all to the other candidates who also volunteered their time.

Thank you. I just want to say that, as I promised in the election, I intend to use mod powers a minimal amount, only in cases of spamming, personal attacks, or similar malicious use. I hope the diamond by my name doesn't change how anyone sees me.

Congratulations!

Congratulations!
And welcome. (Just expressing a wish not a request...) It would be nice if mods had (proper) noun names rather than adjectives

Congratulations!!

This is where "my congratulations Causative, I loved your pitch and think you a great choice" if the code of conduct allowed for such things.  (grins).  If I did comment something such, I may also be in violation of the "do no harm" rule, by risk of causing a swelled noggin,  (grin).  But what the hell... Kudos, +1, well done.

@causative Congratulations and thanks that you will do the job.

@causative Congratulations. Your ideas about moderation are similar to mine.
